# Can someone tell me if the example I wrote below is one possible answer?

Tags: molecular-biology

Here is an imaginary mRNA sequence:
5’- THE BIG BOY SAW THE CAT EAT THE HOT DOG – 3’
Each 3 letter-word is equivalent to the codons in real mRNA.

What would the imaginary mRNA sequence look like if there was a deletion of two bases near the 5’ end of the mRNA? Write out the example above with the two-base deletion and 3-letter “codons” to explain your answer. Label the ends of your imaginary RNA and clearly show the mutation.

I used this: 5’- TBI GBO YSA WTH ECA TEA TTH EHO TDO G-3’. However I am not sure if writing in this form answers the question, can someone tell me whether this is correct and if not how should I change it?

Answer (score 1):

No your answer seems correct, but are you sure they aren't asking you to delete the two bases at the absolute 5' end? In that case it becomes:

5’- EBI GBO YSA WTH ECA TEA TTH EHO TDO G – 3’

But if they're asking you to delete *any* two near the end, then you're correct.

Comment: Okay, is it necessary to put ... at the end of the 3' end for this question?

Comment: I don't understand, I haven't put three dots? It's just G – 3’

Comment: Yeah, that shows that the mRNA is going from 5' to 3' and that it's ending there